# Simplest QT TCP client

Tags: c++, c, qt, network-programming

I would like to connect to a listening server and transmit some data. I looked at the examples available but they seem to have extra functions that do not seem very helpful to me (i.e. connect, *fortune*, etc.). This is the code I have so far:

```
QTcpSocket t;
t.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 9000);
```

Assuming the server is listening and robust, what do I need to implement to send a data variable with datatype `QByteArray`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

very simple with QTcpSocket. Begin as you did...

```
void MainWindow::connectTcp()
{
    QByteArray data; // <-- fill with data

    _pSocket = new QTcpSocket( this ); // <-- needs to be a member variable: QTcpSocket * _pSocket;
    connect( _pSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readTcpData()) );

    _pSocket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 9000);
    if( _pSocket->waitForConnected() ) {
        _pSocket->write( data );
    }
}

void MainWindow::readTcpData()
{
    QByteArray data = pSocket->readAll();
}
```

Be aware, though, that for reading from the TcpSocket you may receive the data in more than one transmission, ie. when the server send you the string "123456" you may receive "123" and "456". It is your responsibility to check whether the transmission is complete. Unfortunately, this almost always results in your class being stateful: the class has to remember what transmission it is expecting, whether it has started already and if it's complete. So far, I haven't figured out an elegant way around that.

Comment: Much obliged Robin, Could you provide some code for receiving data?

Comment: will this bit of the code just be apart of main.cpp or mainwindow.cpp? Also, are there any header files that need to be taken into account?

Comment: @adivk: You can see from the `void MainWindow::` that the methods belong to the MainWindow class. As such they should be in the mainwindow.cpp, and you'll also have to add the declaration in mainwindow.h. As for the header files, you'll probably need both `#include <QByteArray>` and `#include <QTcpSocket>`. Keep in mind, though, that this thread is 4.5 years old and the code above was probably written with Qt4.2. Details may differ if you use a different Qt version.

Comment: would I need anything related to setting up the client in the main.cpp file?

Comment: @adivk: Seems like you have something specific in mind that goes beyond the scope of this question. So why not post your question as a new question? You might be surprised how fast you get high-quality answers! (Don't post questions as comments.)

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was reading xml data, and sometimes I would not get all in one packet.
Here is an elegant solution. WaitForReadyRead could also have a time out in it and
then some extra error checking in case that timeout is reached. In my case I should never
receive an incomplete xml, but if it did happen this would lock the thread up indefinetly
without the timeout:

```
while(!xml.atEnd()) {

    QXmlStreamReader::TokenType t = xml.readNext();

    if(xml.error()) {
        if(xml.error() == QXmlStreamReader::PrematureEndOfDocumentError) {
            cout << "reading extra data" << endl;
            sock->waitForReadyRead();
            xml.addData(sock->readAll());
            cout << "extra data successful" << endl;
            continue;
        }  else {
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
```