# Non blocking threaded tcpi client in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, tcp, client

Please let me explain what is my problem:
I have a Gui application, that has to connect to remote server and keep connected to it for the time untill a user decides to quit the connection, or the server will. I wish to create the client connection mechanism in a separate thread. If the client should be able to asynchronusly receive data and in event driven style inform the main gui thread about it. The thread should also be able to receive data from gui thread to be sent to the server.

I come from a low level microcontroller place, where I would handle this task simply using interrupts and while(1) loop and flags. The problem is on a pc, this would take to much processor time. I have watched and read a lot of tutorials about sockets and threads in qt, but i still dont know what is the best aproach and how to do it properly.

For now, I have a test server on a remote target that is able to receive connections from my Qt client that I am trying to write. I have a class now for my client in Qt, that inherits from Qthread, but then I read that it is not the best aproach anymore.
I wish to create a client instance in new thread (triggered from the gui thread) that will hang forever with exec(). Now I dont know how to handle, using signals the incoming data from the server and incoming commands from the main GUI thread. In general, I would maybe know how to implement this on a low level, but i read about a lot of high level functions for this that qt delivers, i wish to use that.

I would really aprichiate help in this matter. I tried searching, but havent found any solid, working up to date code examples. Could someone please explain me how to create a client instannce in a new thread that wont disconnect after sending/ receiving some data, but instead stay connected and stay responsive to to server calls and gui thread calls in event driven style?

Comment: Would this SO question/answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923485/simplest-qt-tcp-client

Comment: No, its to simple i know this already

Answer (score 1):

May be use general Qt socket mechanism instead separate thread will be better for you. Sockets is very similar to MCU interrupts and simple to use. For your application requests it must be enough.

Comment: It should be in a separate thread not to interfere with the gui mainwindow thread. Mainwindow may throw some modal windows and etc so it is a must.